# Javascript undefined object

Tags: javascript, undefined

I know the best way to check if a variable is undefined is

```
if ( typeof( something ) == "undefined")
```

What I don't understand is when is a variable undefined and when is an object undefined.
For instance when I console.log() the a variable I get

```
Object {detailedView: undefined}
```

My question is why I am getting this and not a plain undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` isn't undefined.  It's defined.  It's an object.  That object just so happens to contain a property that is `undefined`, but the variable itself isn't undefined.

`something` isn't defined, so it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here: the "value" `undefined`, which is a value that a variable can point to when it has been declared but not assigned anything yet (i.e. `var a;`), or when it's been assigned something that doesn't actually have a value or exists, and there is the string `"undefined"`, which is a string similar to "monkey" or "collywobble".

In your conditional, you're testing to see what the result of the `typeof` operator is, which is a string "object" or "function", or in this case "undefined". Those are just words:

```
if(typeof a == "undefined")
```

is the same as testing

```
if(a == undefined)
```

So, when you console.log the actual object, you'll see it has a value `undefined`, rather than being a string `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking about the difference between "undefined variables" (variables never declared) and "undefined values" (the value `undefined` inside a variable or property).

You define/declare a variable with the `var` keyword:

```
var myVariable;
```

If you just do that, the value of that variable is `undefined`:

```
console.log(myVariable); // undefined
```

If you *don't* declare a variable, you cannot use it:

```
console.log(myOtherVariable); // throws a ReferenceError
```

... except in `typeof`:

```
typeof myOtherVariable == "undefined"; // true
```